# Function To check either a string has / or not

Tags: sql, sql-server, user-defined-functions

I want to write a User-Defined function in SQL SERVER which will take a string as parameter and check it if it has a '/' in the string, it'll return 1 and otherwise 0.

Please guide me to achieve this scenario.

Comment: Seems pointless when `CHARINDEX` already exists and tells you what position the character appears in, or 0 if it doesn't appear in the string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unsure why you'd want to make a UDF when TSQL's [`CHARINDEX`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186323.aspx) is all you really need.

Try something like this if you really need a UDF:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.HasSlash(@input varchar(max))
RETURNS bit
AS
BEGIN        
     RETURN CHARINDEX( '/',@input);
END;
```

Use it like this:

```
SELECT dbo.HasSlash('hello/world'); -- returns 1
SELECT dbo.HasSlash('hello world'); -- returns 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example:

```
if OBJECT_ID('dbo.fn_CheckSlash') is not null
    drop function dbo.fn_CheckSlash
go
create function dbo.fn_CheckSlash(
    @str varchar(max))
returns bit
as begin
    return cast(case when @str like '%/%' then 1 else 0 end as bit)
end
go
select dbo.fn_CheckSlash('ac+dc'), dbo.fn_CheckSlash('ac/dc')
```

Outside of practice, you would not create a user-defined function because it adds more complexity than it solves.  You could just use `like '%/%'`.